# chaining classes for .hasClass();

Tags: jquery

Require the following to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/xavi3r/4J583/

```
<div class="cmAuto active a default"></div>
$('body').append("<div>" + $('div').hasClass('.active.default') + "</div>");
```

Output should be TRUE, but it's returning false.

EDIT:

For those looking for the correct code:

http://jsfiddle.net/xavi3r/4J583/8/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`hasClass` takes a single classname.
You should use `.is`, which takes a selector (which can contain multiple classnames).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xavi3r/4J583/8/

.is worked great thanks, just assumed .hasClass would support more than one class, guess my assumption was incorrect, thanks for the help SLaks

Answer (score 1):

I like this one

```
$('body').append("<div>" + ($('div.active.default').length > 0) + "</div>");
```

Comment: You need `.length`.  `$(...)` is always truthy.

Comment: great Joseph +1 thanks for your answer in the end i used .is as it fulfilled my requirements better, but i am grateful for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/4J583/10/

Use **and** `&&` :D

Comment: That would be to match either class, not both.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xavi3r/4J583/6/ shows true for classes that dont have both, see fiddle

Comment: Updated, I've forgot the brackets () :D It should work now :)

Comment: thanks Cristy i went with .is but your contribution is much appreciated +1

Comment: @Cristy  how come hasClass which returns a boolean can be chained ? 
ie: $('div').hasClass('test').addClass('test-new').. how is this working ?