# a selector combined with hasclass() function

Tags: jquery, class, selector

I am now practicing my JS skills and Jquery.

```
var clickcheckboxcount=0; 
var clickedcheckboxname = new Array();
var clickedcheckboxvalue = new Array();
$("#input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
    if ($('div:not([class~=clicked])'){
    $(this).addClass(clickcheckboxcount+'clicked');
    clickedcheckboxname.push($(this).attr("name"));
    clickedcheckboxvalue.push($(this).val());
    clickedcheckboxcount+=1;
}
```

there is serval checkbox with different name and value in HTML body part. I just want to get their attr and name by click them and don't want push same value in the array.  So How can I rewrite if() function.

I put my codes demo in http://jsfiddle.net/Lza2L/

Comment: what are you trying to do

Comment: also the and operator is `&&` not `and`

Comment: You might solution to your querstion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029211/chaining-classes-for-hasclass : use `is`

Comment: Silly me! Thank you ... I am just begin studying JQuery and JS....

Comment: I rewrite my question to be more specific...

Comment: can you share the relevant html also.... and the selector `$("#input[type=checkbox]")` seems to be wrong

Comment: Your logic is merely checking for the existence of a div without that class. It's likely to return true at all times.

Comment: @Arun P Johny I can...but I believe this part is not wrong because this codes can work with if(!$(this).hasClass("0clicked")). But that's also the only one thing I can do...

Comment: @isherwood Sorry I missed a important part! :(

Comment: @isherwood i has a "count" for click event!

Comment: you need to share the complete context.... if possible create a [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [:not](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector:

```
$('div:not(.0clicked,.1clicked,.2clicked,.3clicked,.5clicked,.5clicked)')
```

or [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```
if (!$(this).is(".0clicked, 1clicked, 2clicked, 3clicked, 4clicked, 5clicked"))) {  
    // Your code here
}
```

---

1) You need to include jQuery in your Fiddle

2) Change `#input[type=checkbox]` to `input[type=checkbox]`. `#` used to target `id`. You don't need it here in your selector.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lza2L/1/)**

Comment: not work...I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

I would think an attribute selector combined with `not()` would work in this case:

```
$('div:not([class$=clicked]);
```

This selects elements having a class value that ends with 'clicked'. Of course, complications arise in cases where the element has more than one class.

As Arun points out below, the Contains Word selector may be better suited:

```
$('div:not([class~=clicked]);
```

Comment: you may want to use the [contains word selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/) instead of ends with selector

Comment: True, but I wasn't sure how that would handle spaces, such as between class values.

Comment: when I use it into if()function, it doesn't works :(...

Comment: Without seeing your HTML I can't help much.

Comment: I rewrite my questions...